# Does Net-SNMP only run one handler at a time?

Tags: c, linux, snmp, net-snmp, petalinux

The situation is that multiple MIB custom handlers that access a hardware component if ever there was a time where 2 handlers we running in parallel it would cause errors. NOTE: Get and Set request use the same hardware component.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Questions about installing and configuring software are off topic for StackOverflow unless it concerns programming tools. Please instead post it on ServerFault.com, the site for system administration questions.

Answer (score 0):

Net-SNMP is a protocol stack and not the framework, to make it run on the required platform or hardware you need to give the specific environment or encapsulation which can pick and poke hardware entities and other housekeeping.

For example: A single SNMP stack can run on distributed system having multiple blades and OS instances. And therefore scaling needs to be done by the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Net-SNMP is single-threaded. It can only run one piece of code at a time.